# How to dynamically allocate valueBinding in Ember TextField based on view loading the template

Tags: javascript, ember.js, models, ember-data

I have a few views and they each share the same template. In the template properties of the view that is loading it are used as id, name etc. for various elements.

Among these elements is an input field which I'm trying to have the value bound to an ember-data model. However, I need the value for each input field to be bound to a different property in the model. I'm not sure how to do this using this method of many views using the same template.

Here is a jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/VkKX2/148/) that shows a simple example of this.

This is the template that the views share:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="views">
   {{#each value in controller}}
      {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="value.name"}}
   {{/each}}
</script>
```

I'd like for when each view loads this template, the valueBinding attribute should somehow be assigned to the particular value in the model. Not sure how to do this or if its possible.

Comment: Do you want to iterate through the attributes of your model and have a `TextField` for each one of them? Could you type what you are expecting?

Comment: I would like to have a text field for each one of the model attributes. For example how you can have something like this "<h1>{{view.name}}</h1>" in the template which will show the name attribute of the view that is loading the template. I would like to do something similar with the valueBinding of the TextField